# create one polygon out of different smaller layers

Tags: features

In orange you can see a park. Though I want to create one feature out of all the broken features.

Is this possible?

Also in blue you can see a canal, I want to delete all the lines in between so these will be created into one feature.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have more features like this so i don't want to use the Vertex Tool

Comment: Are you asking how to `dissolve` layers based on attributes?

Comment: Yes, but if i dissolve my features, then I get only a table with 4 features (forest, greenland, pond or river) (see above image), but how do I get my attribute table back together with my previous separate FID from my polygons?

Comment: Then you need to add an ID per entity you want to create and then dissolve by those IDs.

Comment: I added an ID (landuse_1) and a geometry (with geometry by attribute), but I still get an error that I don't have a geometry column..?

Comment: Why do you add a geometry column to the GUI?